# Sets and Relations in Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have not knowledge about relations, could you help me to solve this excercise step by step, to use in futures excercices?

Thanks for your time.

Given the set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $B = \{1, 3, 5\}$, and given the relation $R$ in $B$ defined by
$$a R b \iff a<b$$ describe the couple relationship and its matrix.

Comment: What is the role of the set $A$?

Comment: Hmmm Is R defined only on $B$, so that $a, b\in B$? Or is $a$ from A and $b$ from B?

Answer (score 2):

$(a,b)\in R$ if $a<b$ this means, that $(1,3),(1,5),(2,3),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5)\in R$

Comment: That's good.  And the Matrix?
Well done :)

Comment: Now, with the relation, how can I make its matrix?

Comment: List the elements of A as columns and that of B as rows. Now if $i \in A$ is related $j \in B$ (i.e. $(i,j) \in R$)then mark the $ij$th entry as $1$ otherwise mark it as $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The general way to construct a matrix for a relation between to finite sets $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_m\}$ amd $\{b_1,b_2\dotsb_n\}$ is to create an $m\times n$ matrix X where $x_{i,j}=1$ if $a_i$ is related to $b_i$ and $0$ if they are not related.

In this case the matrix would look like this:

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}$$